# spring Scheduler -runs once in a week

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have to write a spring scheduler which runs once in a week , say every Monday at 1 AM .What will be the cron expression for that , can we archive this using fixedDely.

Answer (score 15):

You can use cron for that:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * MON")
```

In order from left to right of a cron expression:

```
second, minute, hour, day of month, month, day(s) of week
```

Answer (score 2):

A fixed delay is a delay, not a recurring event. With `fixedDelay` you could setup an event that runs after a fixed period in milliseconds between the end of the last invocation and the start of the next. That's not what you want here.

To have a job run every monday at 1 AM you can setup a `cron` expression

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * MON")
```